# How to return Flux of objects after calling a mono boolean method

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-webflux, project-reactor

I have a validator method that returns a `Mono<Boolean>`.
The validation is happening as expected and returns bad request exception in case of invalid `id1` or `id2`.

```
public static Mono<Boolean> validate(String id1, String id2) {
   //some condition to check id1 & id2.
   // either return Mono.just(false)/mono.just(true)
   // or return Mono.error(new BadRequestException("")); 
}
```

However, the control is going to the next line instead of returning from the execution.
Here is the method where the validator method is referred:

```
public Flux<FacilitiesResponse> validateAndGetFacilityResponse(String id1, String id2) {
    validate(id1,id2);
    return facilityService.getFacilityResponse(id1,id2);  
 }
```

The validator method returns `Mono<Boolean>`, but the method returns `Flux<FacilitiesResponse>`. How to re-write this whole method in `reactive` way such that it returns `Flux< FacilitiesResponse>` ?

I tried something like below:

```
return validate(id1,id2)
       .filter(valid -> valid)
       .map(valid -> facilityService.getFacilityResponse(id1,id2))
```

but it gives me `Mono<Flux< FacilitiesResponse>>` instead.

Unfortunately,  I cannot change the return type of `facilityService.getFacilityResponse(id1,id2)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your first example nothing happens with `validate(id1,id2);` because no one subscribes to it. You should build your reactive chain from the start to the end.

To return `Flux` after the successful validation you should use `flatMapMany()`

```java
return validate(id1,id2)
        .filter(valid -> valid)
        .flatMapMany(__ -> facilityService.getFacilityResponse(id1,id2));
```

From `flatMapMany()` docs:

```
 * Transform the item emitted by this {@link Mono} into a Publisher, then forward  * its emissions into the returned {@link Flux}.
```

Answer (score 1):

The `Mono` has this operator:

```
/**
 * Transform the item emitted by this {@link Mono} into a Publisher, then forward
 * its emissions into the returned {@link Flux}.
 *
 * <p>
 * <img class="marble" src="doc-files/marbles/flatMapMany.svg" alt="">
 *
 * @param mapper the
 * {@link Function} to produce a sequence of R from the eventual passed {@link Subscriber#onNext}
 * @param <R> the merged sequence type
 *
 * @return a new {@link Flux} as the sequence is not guaranteed to be single at most
 */
public final <R> Flux<R> flatMapMany(Function<? super T, ? extends Publisher<? extends R>> mapper) {
```

Comment: Thank you, `flatMapmany` after the filter gives me the expected response!